# Search special String pattern using Binding operator in Perl

Tags: perl, scripting, pattern-matching

I have one perl script which parse the log and search for perticular pattern like Error, Fatal and decide the Pass and Fail status. 
Coming to my question I need to search uniq pattern like "Error (E302/FEP0512SRA)" if such pattern is presnet in any line of Log file it should increase error_cnt by 1.

I tried "\" and Below approch but in both case i got fail to capture above mention patter.

```
my $str = "Error (E302/FEP0512SRA)";
if($line =~ /$str/) {
      $error_cnt++;      
}
```

Please let me know what else i can do so i can catch this string in my log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string contains [regex metacharacters](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Metacharacters) (the parentheses).  You should either escape them by hand, or use `quotemeta`:

```
my $str = quotemeta "Error (E302/FEP0512SRA)";
```

Answer (score 2):

Regexes contain many operators, so-called metacharacters. Parens `()` are such metacharacters and have to be escaped. Perl provides the `quotemeta` function for that. Inside a regex, we can use the equivalent `\Q...\E` environment, which takes care of that for us. Then:

```
$error_cnt++ if $line =~ /\Q$str\E/;
```

Comment: Thanks amon...it worked :) I tried google this issue but couldnt find any description like meta-character...I would like to know if you have any pdf or know any good side to learn this basics more efficiently.

Comment: @vjain419 Perl has loads of documentation you can read – a good place to start is the [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html). Later, `perlre` is an advanced reference.